# Nvapi how to use it in python3?

Tags: python, ctypes

Hello I'm trying to set three parameters using ctypes,

```
import ctypes

brightness = 52
contrast = 27
gamma = 1.40

def setBrightness(brightness):
    nvapi = ctypes.WinDLL("nvapi64.dll")
    handle = ctypes.c_uint()
    nvapi.NvAPI_Initialize()
    nvapi.NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUsFromDisplay(ctypes.byref(handle))
    nvapi.NvAPI_GPU_SetBrightness(handle.value, ctypes.c_uint(brightness))
    nvapi.NvAPI_Unload()

def setContrast(contrast):
    nvapi = ctypes.WinDLL("nvapi64.dll")
    handle = ctypes.c_uint()
    nvapi.NvAPI_Initialize()
    nvapi.NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUsFromDisplay(ctypes.byref(handle))
    nvapi.NvAPI_GPU_SetContrast(handle.value, ctypes.c_uint(contrast))
    nvapi.NvAPI_Unload()

def setGamma(gamma):
    nvapi = ctypes.WinDLL("nvapi64.dll")
    handle = ctypes.c_uint()
    nvapi.NvAPI_Initialize()
    nvapi.NvAPI_GetPhysicalGPUsFromDisplay(ctypes.byref(handle))
    nvapi.NvAPI_GPU_SetGamma(handle.value, ctypes.c_float(gamma))
    nvapi.NvAPI_Unload()

setBrightness(brightness)
setContrast(contrast)
setGamma(gamma)
```

but I'm getting:

```
  File "C:\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 391, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'NvAPI_Initialize' not found
```

How can I fix this?

I'm trying to set parameters.

Comment: The error indicates `NvAPI_Initialize` isn't exported from `nvapi64.dll` or isn't spelled correctly.  You can use a tool like `dumpbin /exports nvapi64.dll` to see what functions are exported.

Comment: Also, which line shown fails?  There aren't 391 lines.  Try commenting out the unload commands.  Maybe once unloaded the 2nd initialize fails.  Why not initialize once at the top?

Comment: there is an autohotkey version of this library here https://github.com/jNizM/NVIDIA_NvAPI/blob/master/src/Class_NvAPI.ahk you can check it